# How to fix broken height adjustment casters on a shelf?

Tags: shelving

I removed some shelving from a closet, in order to replace the carpet. I did not realize at the time, but this shelving had a rather nice angle adjustment system - you can pop off a plastic piece, and then change the height of the caster using a Phillips screwdriver.

Since I did not know about this, I removed the shelves by force and broke the part that attaches to the bottom of the shelf. It looks like particle board.

Do you have any great ideas on how I could reattach this system and have it be useful again? The anchor part does not want to stick to the particle board, as the holes have been broken open too widely.

[image: height adjustment caster for front of shelf - the top part is a Phillips head screw] [image: busted up particle board]
[image: how it is supposed to look]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Fill the holes. Re-drill it.

Comment: @Tetsujin that sounds totally reasonable - what I don't understand is how that metal part is supposed to connect to the particle board in the first place. Do I just hammer it in?

Comment: That would have been the original install method, yes - though by machine rather than 'man with hammer who hopes to still have fingers tomorrow' . You could just try glue it in with something hard-setting. Make sure you don't leak into the threaded section.

Comment: @Tetsujin That worked like a charm (made a new hole, will fill in the old later). Thanks so much! If you want to make that an answer I am happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After comments…

Simply refill, redrill; or glue it in place.

As it's just a resting point for a shelf, its absolute position isn't vital, so you can glue into the existing hole, or just make a new one nearby. The threaded collar just hammers into the new hole or glues back into the old one, so long as you don't get glue in the thread.

Comment: Yup. That's called a "T-nut" and simply hammers into the hole. Since you've got a particle board shelf, you may want to give it a light tap to mark where the prongs go, pull it back out, then using a _very small_ bit, make a pilot hole for each of the prongs, then hammer it back in.  Make sure you place the new hole far enough from the old one that there's enough surface so the new hole doesn't break into the old one and fail.